# Install Ralink corp. RT2800 drivers in lubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, dell, ralink

I recently installed Lubuntu on my old Dell Optiplex GX270. It originally had windows XP. I had some problems with the drivers in Windows as well. After installing Lubuntu I cannot connect to the internet or see any nearby networks. I can't use apt-get or wget because of this, however I can use a different computer and move any necessary files. Can someone please give detailed, step-by-step instructions for how I could go about installing any necessary drivers and what else I should do to connect to the internet.

PS. I'll be happy to give any other details if they are necessary.

Comment: They are probably already installed. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsmod | grep rt2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the output as an image since I couldn't paste it directly to Ask Ubuntu. Here's a link to the image: https://ibb.co/b4h5tS

Comment: As you see, the driver is already installed and loaded. May we also see: `dmesg | grep rt2` and: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Here is the output of both: https://ibb.co/f1ivtS . You said that the drivers are installed already, if it's not the drivers then what could the problem be and how could I fix it? (I'm a noob to Lubuntu).

Comment: "then what could the problem be and how could I fix it?" That's what we're trying to find out. So far, we see nothing at all wrong. Next, let's see: `dmesg | grep wlp` and: `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: "That's what we're trying to find out" fair point. Here's the two commands and the output: https://ibb.co/mdKUL7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73998/discussion-between-chili555-and-user9123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our chat, we determined that the Optiplex doesn't come with wireless by default. The fact that you also had problems in Windows suggests that it's a hardware; i.e. physical layer, issue.

The fact that the driver is present, there are no errors in the log and the result of scanning is not an error or a warning but, "no scan results" made me wonder if the antenna is present or, if it's present, if it has become dislodged and not securely attached.

In order to add wireless, you, or a previous owner, added a PCI wireless card; something like this:

[image]

I suggested that you check the antennae to be certain they were securely attached. You found them loose, tightened them and the wireless then scanned and connected.